# Are there maximum principles related to the third boundary condition?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I am working on this problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u''(s)+\frac{2}{s} u'(s)=R^2 f(u) \quad \text{ for } \eta<s<1, \\
u'(\eta)=0, \ u'(1)+\beta R (u(1)-\bar{\sigma})=0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $R, \beta, \bar{\sigma}>0$, $0 \leq \eta <1$ are constants, $f \in C^1[0,+\infty)$, $f'$ is positive and bounded on $[0,+\infty)$, and $f$ attains $0$ only at the point $\sigma_0 \geq 0$.

It has been proved that this problem has a unique solution $u(s)=U(s,\eta,R)$ with $\sigma_0<u<\bar{\sigma}$ for all $\eta \leq s \leq 1$. What I want to show next is that $U(s,\eta,R)$ is strictly decreasing in $R$ for $\eta \leq s<1$. To do this, denote $v(s)=\frac{\partial U(s,\eta,R)}{\partial R}$, then $v$ solves the following problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
v''(s)+\frac{2}{s} v'(s)=2Rf(u)+R^2 f'(u)v \quad \text{ for } \eta<s<1, \\
v'(\eta)=0, \ v'(1)+\beta R v(1)=-\beta (u(1)-\bar{\sigma}).
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Also, it has been proved that $u'(1)>0$, thereby $-\beta (u(1)-\bar{\sigma})=\frac{u'(1)}{R}>0$ follows. With all those prepared, I want to use the maximum principle to prove that $v(s)<0$ for $\eta \leq s<1$, only to see that neither can I find existing results in textbooks or other papers nor conceive a proof by myself.

Could anyone please tell me where to refer to for them, or provide some ideas on how to tackle this kind of problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe that there is a typo: Either the first equation should read $\frac{2}{s}u'(s)$ in the first-order term, or the equation for $v(s)$ is wrong and should include a term $-\frac{2u'(s)}{u^2(s)}v(s)$ arising from the linearization of $\frac{2}{u(s)}u'(s)$. I strongly suspect the first option...

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Sorry there is a typo in the first equation, should have been $\frac{2}{s} u'(s)$. Thank you very much.